# Why would my XmlReader return an empty string?

Tags: .net, xml, xmlreader

I need to get the full Xml string from an XmlReader (long story).  In this sample code though, the final variable, theXmlString, remains empty. Why does it not get assigned the Xml string?

```
string xmlConfig = @"<pdfMappings>
                        <pdfFile formTypeEnum=""Int_UT_Additional_Investment_Form_Ind_And_LE_direct"">
                            <perspective ngiAdminPerspectiveName=""Investor"">
                                <fieldMapping fieldName=""topmostsubform[0].Page2[0].first_names[0]"" mapTo=""CurrentInvolvedParty.FirstName""></fieldMapping>
                                <fieldMapping fieldName=""topmostsubform[0].Page2[0].surname[0]"" mapTo=""CurrentInvolvedParty.LastName""></fieldMapping>
                            </perspective>
                        </pdfFile>
                    </pdfMappings>";
var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlConfig));

string theXmlString = reader.ReadOuterXml();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just need to start reading first, use `Read()` to move to the node then `ReadOuterXml()` to actually read the value.

```
var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlConfig));
reader.Read();
string theXmlString = reader.ReadOuterXml();
```

Alternatively you should also be able to use `reader.MoveToContent();`.

Comment: As simple as that. Thanks rRrRrRr